# Single Word Request: Relationship based on context

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single adjective or noun that means "the right person for the situation"? I'm specifically looking for a word like "condign," "complimentary," "appropriate," "convenient," "codependent," or "mutualistic," but pertaining specifically to a relationship between two people **and** formed solely because of their situation. Think of two people who bond during an NA group meeting, or who become inseparable after both surviving a trauma, etc.

> "When the battered plane landed and the survivors disembarked, they became ______."
>
> "He's rich, she's broke; they're ______."
>
> "They're work friends! That's how they get through the day -- she's his _______ !"

I realize you could fill in the blanks with a lot of things, but I've done some searches through the internet and my thesaurus, and I can't find anything with the right flavor. Any suggestions would help, help at least to narrow it down. I'm not opposed to making up a word, I just want to exhaust the possibilities.

This is my first time asking, so if I can clarify anything or need to correct my formatting, I'm open to suggestions. (And I hope this isn't too broad.) Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

See **symbiotic**, defined by [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/symbiotic) as

> living in symbiosis, or having an interdependent relationship.
>
> [Symbiosis](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/symbiosis) -   a cooperative relationship

They could also be **anaclitic**.

> **[Anaclisis](http://psychologydictionary.org/anaclisis/)** - a significant reliance upon someone else for emotional and physical strength and reassurance.

Keep in mind that an anaclitic relationship has other meanings as well depending on field of study, for example medicine, psychoanalysis, etc.

Comment: "anaclitic" -- absolutely wonderful word, and pretty darn close. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[Partner.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/partner)

> "*Partners in crime.*"   "*When the battered plane landed and the
>   survivors disembarked, they became partners...*"
>   "*They're work
>   friends! That's how they get through the day -- she's his partner!*"

Alternatively, you may prefer [Companion](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/companion) for a positive connotation.

Answer (score 0):

In all of the example phrases you mentioned, I think you could use **adjunct.**

> attached or belonging without full or permanent status

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/adjunct?s=t